# "Environment subfigure undefined" on journal submission

Tags: floats, subfloats, sv-classes

I have a LaTeX file with packages

```
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,citecolor=black,linkcolor=black,urlcolor=blue]{hyperref}
\usepackage{tikz,graphics,color,fullpage,float,epsf,caption,subcaption}
```

and I use the `subfigure` environment:

```
\begin{figure}
\begin{subfigure}{1\textwidth}
...
\end{subfigure}

\vspace{5mm}

\begin{subfigure}{1\textwidth}
...
\end{subfigure}

\end{figure}
```

This compiles perfectly fine on my machine. However, when I submit the LaTeX file to a journal and looks at the PDF output, it shows an error

```
! LaTeX Error: Environment subfigure undefined.
```

I'm really lost on how to fix this, since as I said, it works fine on my machine. What should I do?

**EDIT**: I'm using the document class

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}
```

This site seems to have some information on the document class if necessary: http://www.e-publications.org/springer/support/spr-chicago.html

Comment: What document class are you using? Note also that `hyperref` should be loaded later than all those packages and that `epsf` should *not* be loaded.

Comment: to add to egreg's comment, since `graphicx` loads `graphics`, the latter is also unnecessary.

Comment: `tikz` loads an enhanced version of `color` so `color` is not needed either.

Comment: Your link points to bibstyle doc and not to class doc.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would suggest a work-around, if all else fails, as it is difficult to test this without going through the submission process yourself. In that regard, avoid using the `subfigure` environment altogether, and default to using a `tabular` structure for arranging your subfigures. While this comes with manual numbering of subfigures, it's not that difficult to maintain references manually.

Here's a minimal example that should show you the implementation:

[image]

```
\documentclass[smallextended]{svjour3}
\usepackage{lipsum}% Just for this example
\usepackage{graphicx}
\begin{document}

See Figure~\ref{fig:myfig}(a) or~(b). \lipsum[1]

\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
    \includegraphics[width=.7\linewidth,height=75pt]{example-image-a} \\[\abovecaptionskip]
    \small (a) An image
  \end{tabular}

  \vspace{\floatsep}

  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}}
    \includegraphics[width=.6\linewidth,height=100pt]{example-image-b} \\[\abovecaptionskip]
    \small (b) Another image
  \end{tabular}

  \caption{This is a figure caption}\label{fig:myfig}
\end{figure}

\lipsum[2]

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 42):

or you can try:

```
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup{compatibility=false}
```

Comment: So weird that this works, but `\usepackage{subfig}` doesn't. Oh well.

Answer (score 2):

As you have mentioned that you add the package `subcaption`:

```
\usepackage{tikz,graphics,color,fullpage,float,epsf,caption,subcaption}
```

You can then do the following ways to work around this (which in my case is working):

**Using the subcaptiongroup environment**

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subcaptiongroup}
    \centering
    \parbox[b]{.4\textwidth}{%
    \centering
    \includegraphics{cat}
    \caption{A cat}\label{cat}}%
    \parbox[b]{.4\textwidth}{%
    \centering
    \includegraphics{elephant}
    \caption{An elephant}\label{elephant}}%
  \end{subcaptiongroup}
  \caption{Two animals}\label{animals}
\end{figure}
```

[image: Sample 1]

Your output will be still the same and the conflict of the error with the subfigure should now have disappeared.

For the subfigure, you can also use `\phantomcaption`:

```
\begin{figure}
  \centering
  \begin{subcaptiongroup}
    \includegraphics{cat_with_a}
    \phantomcaption\label{cat}
    \includegraphics{elephant_with_b}
    \phantomcaption\label{elephant}
  \end{subcaptionblock}
  \captionsetup{subrefformat=parens}
  \caption{Two animals: \subref{cat} a cat, and \subref{elephant} an 
  elephant}
\label{animals}
\end{figure}
```

Also, by working around with the `subcaption` package:

```
\usepackage{subcaption}
\captionsetup[sub]{⟨options⟩}
```

The default settings for sub-captions are:

```
margin=0pt,font+=smaller,labelformat=parens,labelsep=space,
skip=6pt,list=false,hypcap=false
```

Answer (score 0):

Look at this link:
https://dev.to/latexteada/latex-more-in-figures-side-by-side-figures-44i3
Ultimately all you have to do is:

```
\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{//path} % Just stack two includegraphics!
\includegraphics[width=.3\linewidth]{\\path}
\caption{A subfigure}
\label{fig:sub1}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Ths doesn't answer to OP which asks for  `\includegraphics` on top of each other. And doesn't in anyway fixes the subcaption issue.

Comment: I do not know why this answer got thumbs down, actually in some contexts, it also works. To further modify you even can add `\hfill` or `\vfill`  in between two `\includegraphics`

Answer (score -1):

The captionsetup did not work for me but i could keep the same structure by simply exchanging the `subfigure` parts with `minipage` like this:

```
\begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=4.5cm]{images/test1.JPG} 
        \caption{Test 1}
    \end{minipage}
    \hfill
    \begin{minipage}{0.49\textwidth}
        \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, height=4.5cm]{images/test2.JPG}
        \caption{Test 2}
    \end{minipage}
\caption{Test figures for minipage \cite{testReference}}
\label{fig:test}
\end{figure}
```

Comment: Welcome on tex.sx. Your solution as presented won't compile. To enable the use of `\caption` in a minipage, you w'd need some `\captionsetup` in preamble or in the minipage.