# How to add multiple subfigures to figure environment

Tags: floats, subfloats

Using [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196653/how-do-i-stack-two-figures-on-top-of-each-other-rather-than-side-to-side) I tried to add multiple pairs of subfigures to my latex document

```
\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{borland}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\mintinline{c}{#1}}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\subsection{\code{process_select()}}

The following diagrams show how  \code{process_select()} would modify the \code{queue} and \code{current_process} for test \code{lab3_t0.c}.

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{process_select1}
   \caption{\code{queue}}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{process_select2}
   \caption{\code{current_process}}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Initially \code{queue} would hold both processes, but \code{current_process} would not be set since \code{process_select()} has not been called so no \code{current_process} has been set}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{process_select3}
   \caption{\code{queue}}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=1\linewidth]{process_select4}
   \caption{\code{current_process}}
\end{subfigure}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

But nothing shows up!

But when I change the `width` of the last 2 subfigures to `width=0.5\linewidth`:

```
\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{process_select3}
   \caption{\code{queue}}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{process_select4}
   \caption{\code{current_process}}
\end{subfigure}
```

It shows up but not the way I want it to:
[image]

What I want is for the `process_select3` and `process_select4` to show up in the same size as `process_select1` and `process_select2`.  I also have an additional 2 subfigures `process_select5` and `proceess_select6` that I want to add, which I tried using:

```
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{process_select5}
   \caption{\code{queue}}
\end{subfigure}

\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=0.5\linewidth]{process_select6}
   \caption{\code{current_process}}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{After second call to \code{process_select()} \code{current_process} would be set to the next process in the \code{queue} (\code{p2}) and since the \code{p1} is still running, it would be appended to the end of the queue}
```

But sadly nothing showed up when I added that code in the `\begin{figure}...\end{figure}` environment

If anyone could provide me the latex code to make all 6 of my subfigures (`process_select1-6`) show up with the same width as the first 2 subfigures (`process_select3` and `process_select4`) and also have a caption for each pair of subfigures, that would be great!

Comment: I cant reproduce your problem. With the first code in your question I obtain expected result. Off topic: why you have caption on middle of the figure and not bottom, where usually is? By the way, in your MWE is missed `\documentclass{...}˙`

Comment: @Zarko I've added my whole code. I didn't want to add my whole code b/c I didn't think they affected my results, but based on your comment there might be smtg I'm overlooking. Please let me know. And I added captions "in the middle of the figure" because I want to have caption for every 2 picture (i.e. a caption for `process_select 1` & `process_select2`, a caption for `process_select3` & `process_select4`, and a caption for `process_select5` & `process_select6`). But perhaps I am doing this wrong?

Comment: please, make your question shorter. one MWE is sufficient :)

Comment: okay I'll delete the code. jw, what do you mean by MWE?

Comment: MWE: Minimal Working Example. A small complete (self contained) document with `\documentclass{...}` on its beginning and `end{document}` on its end :), which show the your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only guessing what you like to obtain ... but I'm not sure, if the following result is what you looking for:

[image]

In my MWE instead of your image I use `demo` images, which are provided by `graphicx` package (option`demo`). IN compa\hsil:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,openright,oneside]{article}
\usepackage{minted}
\usemintedstyle{borland}
\newcommand{\code}[1]{\mintinline{c}{#1}}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\begin{document}
\subsection{\code{process_select()}}

The following diagrams show how  \code{process_select()} would modify the \code{queue} and \code{current_process} for test \code{lab3_t0.c}.

\begin{figure}[h]
\centering
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{process_select1}
   \caption{\code{queue}}
\end{subfigure}
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{process_select2}
   \caption{\code{current_process}}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Initially \code{queue} would hold both processes, but \code{current_process} would not be set since \code{process_select()} has not been called so no \code{current_process} has been set}
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{process_select3}
   \caption{\code{queue}}
\end{subfigure}
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{process_select4}
   \caption{\code{current_process}}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Initially \code{queue} would hold both processes, but \code{current_process} would not be set since \code{process_select()} has not been called so no \code{current_process} has been set}

\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.6\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{process_select5}
   \caption{\code{queue}}
\end{subfigure}
\hfil
\begin{subfigure}[t]{0.3\textwidth}
   \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{process_select6}
   \caption{\code{current_process}}
\end{subfigure}

\caption{Initially \code{queue} would hold both processes, but \code{current_process} would not be set since \code{process_select()} has not been called so no \code{current_process} has been set}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```