# Aligning multiple subfigures in figure

Tags: floats, subcaption, chemfig

I'm using the `chemfig` package for some structural diagrams I'm preparing for a lab report, and I need to align five structural diagrams (with their own name captions) in a 2x3 column-and-row format. To this end, I chose to use `chemfig` within multiple `subfigure` environments, all within a `figure`.

I used [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/119984/subfigures-side-by-side-with-captions) as well as [this one](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/196653/how-do-i-stack-two-figures-on-top-of-each-other-rather-than-side-to-side) to begin to understand how to do the horizontal and vertical alignment within a `figure` environment, but I'm running into the issue where the `figure` environment "forgets" the row alignment after the first row.

The MWE is as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{baskervald}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[h]
    \centering
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \scalebox{0.67}{
            \chemfig{HO-[:30]*6(-=-(-\chemabove{N}{H}-[::-60](=[::-60]O)-)=-=)}
        }
        \caption{Acetaminophen}
    \end{subfigure}%
    ~
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \scalebox{0.67}{
            \chemfig{*6(-=-(-O-[::-60](=[::-60]O)-[::+60])=(-(=[::+60])-[::-60]OH)-=)}
        }
        \caption{Aspirin}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \\
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \scalebox{0.67}{
            \chemfig{*6((=O)-N(-CH_3)-*5(-N=-N(-CH_3)-=)--(=O)-N(-H_3C)-)}
        }
        \caption{Caffeine}
    \end{subfigure}
    ~   
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \scalebox{0.67}{
            \chemfig{H_3C-[::30](-[:90]CH_3)-[::-60]-[::60]*6(-=-(-(-[::60]CH_3)-[::-60](=[::-60]O)-OH)=-=)}
        }
        \caption{Ibuprofen}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \\
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.5\textwidth}
        \centering
        \scalebox{0.67}{
            \chemfig{*6(-=-(-OH)=(-(=[::60]O)-[::-60]NH_2)-=)}
        }
        \caption{Salicylamide}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \caption{Chemical structures of the analgesics being analyzed.}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

This results in the following output:

[image: MWE output]

Here, I need figures (a) and (b) to be aligned horizontally, as they are, with (c) and (d) aligned similarly beneath them, and (e) centered between the two (as it currently is) beneath that.

I've tried two routes to remedy this, neither of which have had any success in remedying the issue:

- Blocking each row in braces, then using `\\` to separate rows
- Placing each row within its own `subfigure` environment.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about using a `tabular` for that?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{baskervald}
\usepackage{chemfig}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure*}[h]
\centering
  \begin{tabular}{@{}c@{}@{}c@{}}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \scalebox{0.67}{
            \chemfig{HO-[:30]*6(-=-(-\chemabove{N}{H}-[::-60](=[::-60]O)-)=-=)}
        }
        \caption{Acetaminophen}
    \end{subfigure}
    &
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \scalebox{0.67}{
            \chemfig{*6(-=-(-O-[::-60](=[::-60]O)-[::+60])=(-(=[::+60])-[::-60]OH)-=)}
        }
        \caption{Aspirin}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \\
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \scalebox{0.67}{
            \chemfig{*6((=O)-N(-CH_3)-*5(-N=-N(-CH_3)-=)--(=O)-N(-H_3C)-)}
        }
        \caption{Caffeine}
    \end{subfigure}
    &   
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \scalebox{0.67}{
            \chemfig{H_3C-[::30](-[:90]CH_3)-[::-60]-[::60]*6(-=-(-(-[::60]CH_3)-[::-60](=[::-60]O)-OH)=-=)}
        }
        \caption{Ibuprofen}
    \end{subfigure}%
    \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{\begin{subfigure}[b]{0.45\textwidth}
        \centering
        \scalebox{0.67}{
            \chemfig{*6(-=-(-OH)=(-(=[::60]O)-[::-60]NH_2)-=)}
        }
        \caption{Salicylamide}
    \end{subfigure}%
    }
  \end{tabular} 
\caption{Chemical structures of the analgesics being analyzed.}
\end{figure*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This worked wonderfully! I had considered a `tabular` approach, but I think I got too engrained in the `subfigure` way of doing things and didn't think of this.